# How to Optimise code to retrieve user NickName by querying fields from a custom object

Tags: soql, map, set, variable

I have currently have a code that sends alerts to **Head of Service**(user) of a **Business Unit**. So if a case has been created for the **business Unit **APAC**** for example, an alert is sent the the **Head of Service APAC**(e.g John Smith)

My code works fine but it is definitely not the best way of writing the logic as I do multiple if statements to go through all business Units and send the alert to the appropriate Head of Service.

here is the initial code:

```
public class SlackNotificationHeadOfService {

public class slackRequest { 
    @InvocableVariable(label='caseNumber')
    public String caseNumber;
    @InvocableVariable(label='status')
    public String status;
    @InvocableVariable(label='nickName')
    public String nickname;
    @InvocableVariable(label='queue')
    public String queue;
    @InvocableVariable(label='accountTier')
    public String accountTier;
    @InvocableVariable(label='accountName')
    public String accountName;
    @InvocableVariable(label='subject')
    public String subject;
    @InvocableVariable(label='businessUnit')
    public String businessUnit;
} 

public static String setSlackUserNickName(String businessUnit) {
    String channelName;
    
    if (businessUnit == 'Brazil (BR)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_BR+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'Central & Eastern Europe (CEE)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_CEE+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'China (CN)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_CN+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'Germany (DACH)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_DACH+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'France (FR)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_FR+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'Italy (IT)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_IT+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'Latin America (LatAm)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_LatAm+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'New Markets (NM)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_NM+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'Spain (ES)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_ES+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'United States (US)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_US+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'United Kingdom (UK)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_UK+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'Asia Pacific (APAC)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_APAC+'';
    else if (businessUnit == 'Middle East & North Africa (MENA)')
        channelName = ''+Label.HeadOfService_MENA+'';
    
    return channelName;
}

public static String setChannelName(String queue) {

    String channelName;
    queue = 'caseconcern';

    channelName = '#'+queue;
    channelName = channelName.toLowerCase('en');
    channelName = channelName.replaceAll('queue', 'bot');
    channelName = channelName.replaceAll('[_]', '-');
    return channelName;
}

@InvocableMethod(label='Publish to Head of Service')
public static void publishToSlack(List<slackRequest> requests) {

    //String webhookURL='https://hooks.slack.com/services/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';
    String webhookURL = system.label.Param_Slack_Token;
    String msg;
    String channelName;

    for(slackRequest r:requests){

            System.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport new case concern');
            channelName = setSlackUserNickName(r.businessUnit);
            
            msg = 'A new Case Concern has been created : *'+r.caseNumber+'* - By User : (*'+r.nickName+' '+r.accountName+'* From *'+r.accountTier+'*) - Category : (*'+r.subject+'*)';
            msg += '\nLink to Case Concern : '+URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+r.status;
                  
        // Generate JSON for request
        try {
            if (r.queue != null || r.nickname != null) {
                System.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport Sending message');
                JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
                gen.writeStartObject(); //Inserts {
                gen.writeStringField('text', msg);
                gen.writeStringField('channel', channelName);
                gen.writeStringField('username', 'bot-support');
                gen.writeStringField('icon_emoji', ':smartplus:');
                gen.writeEndObject(); //Inserts }
                String body = gen.getAsString(); //Translates JSONGenerator to string to be passed to callout
                System.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport body: '+ body);
                System.enqueueJob(new qCallOut(webhookURL, 'POST', body)); // Send request
            }
            else {
                System.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport Queue = '+ r.queue);
                return;
            }
        }     
        catch (exception e){
            system.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport error:' + e);
        }
    } 
}

public class qCallOut implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
     
    private final String url;
    private final String method;
    private final String body;
     
    public qCallOut(String url, String method, String body) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.body = body;
    }
     
    public void execute(System.QueueableContext ctx) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setBody(body);
        Http http = new Http();
        // to pass when process builder is invoked by another test class
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){  
          HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        }
    }
}

}
```

My org has a custom object "**Application_Parameters__c**" that has records for the Head of Service for each Business Unit. So theorically, I should be able to achieve the exact same thing that with the multiple if Statement in just a few lines

[image]

On the following code, I have created a Map to get the **Head_Of_Service__c** of the corresponding **Business_Unit__c**.
Then, store the IDs in a set to finally be able to send an alert to the **Head_of_Service__C** using the User Nickname.

My logic is obviously wrong has I get an error for:

```
        channelName = ''+headOfService_ids.get(Id).CommunityNickname+'';
```

Which makes sense since I have not declared Id... But I do not know how to get the **Head_Of_Service__c**  from the object Application_Parameters__c to send him an alert depending on the **Business_Unit__c**

Here is the code with the error:

```
public class SlackNotificationHeadOfService {

public class slackRequest { 
    @InvocableVariable(label='caseNumber')
    public String caseNumber;
    @InvocableVariable(label='status')
    public String status;
    @InvocableVariable(label='nickName')
    public String nickname;
    @InvocableVariable(label='queue')
    public String queue;
    @InvocableVariable(label='accountTier')
    public String accountTier;
    @InvocableVariable(label='accountName')
    public String accountName;
    @InvocableVariable(label='subject')
    public String subject;
    @InvocableVariable(label='businessUnit')
    public String businessUnit;
} 

public static String setSlackUserNickName(String businessUnit) {
    String channelName;
    Set<ID> headOfService_ids = new Set<ID>();
    
    Map<Id, Application_Parameters__c> headOfService = New Map<Id, Application_Parameters__c>(
        [SELECT Id, Head_of_Service__c FROM Application_Parameters__c WHERE Business_Unit__c = :businessUnit]);
 
    for(Application_Parameters__c app : headOfService.values()) {
        headOfService_ids.add(app.Head_of_Service__c);
    }
     
    channelName = ''+headOfService_ids.get(Id).CommunityNickname+'';
    
    return channelName;
}

public static String setChannelName(String queue) {

    String channelName;
    queue = 'caseconcern';

    channelName = '#'+queue;
    channelName = channelName.toLowerCase('en');
    channelName = channelName.replaceAll('queue', 'bot');
    channelName = channelName.replaceAll('[_]', '-');
    return channelName;
}

@InvocableMethod(label='Publish to Head of Service')
public static void publishToSlack(List<slackRequest> requests) {

    //String webhookURL='https://hooks.slack.com/services/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';
    String webhookURL = system.label.Param_Slack_Token;
    String msg;
    String channelName;
    
    for(slackRequest r:requests){

            System.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport new case concern');
            channelName = setSlackUserNickName(r.businessUnit);
            
            msg = 'A new Case Concern has been created : *'+r.caseNumber+'* - By User : (*'+r.nickName+' '+r.accountName+'* From *'+r.accountTier+'*) - Category : (*'+r.subject+'*)';
            msg += '\nLink to Case Concern : '+URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+r.status;
                  
        // Generate JSON for request
        try {
            if (r.queue != null || r.nickname != null) {
                System.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport Sending message');
                JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
                gen.writeStartObject(); //Inserts {
                gen.writeStringField('text', msg);
                gen.writeStringField('channel', channelName);
                gen.writeStringField('username', 'bot-support');
                gen.writeStringField('icon_emoji', ':smartplus:');
                gen.writeEndObject(); //Inserts }
                String body = gen.getAsString(); //Translates JSONGenerator to string to be passed to callout
                System.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport body: '+ body);
                System.enqueueJob(new qCallOut(webhookURL, 'POST', body)); // Send request
            }
            else {
                System.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport Queue = '+ r.queue);
                return;
            }
        }     
        catch (exception e){
            system.debug('### SlackNotificationSupport error:' + e);
        }
    } 
}

public class qCallOut implements System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
     
    private final String url;
    private final String method;
    private final String body;
     
    public qCallOut(String url, String method, String body) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.body = body;
    }
     
    public void execute(System.QueueableContext ctx) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setBody(body);
        Http http = new Http();
        // to pass when process builder is invoked by another test class
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){  
          HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good night sleep is sometimes the best way to solve your issue.
I managed to find what I was doing wrong. I was trying to use a get() method on a Set which obviously cannot work.

I updated my method **setSlackUserNickName**

```
public static String setSlackUserNickName(String businessUnit) {
String channelName;
Set<ID> headOfService_ids = new Set<ID>();

Map<Id, Application_Parameters__c> headOfService = New Map<Id, Application_Parameters__c>(
    [SELECT Id, Head_of_Service__c FROM Application_Parameters__c WHERE Business_Unit__c = :businessUnit]);

for(Application_Parameters__c app : headOfService.values()) {
    headOfService_ids.add(app.Head_of_Service__c);
}
 
channelName = ''+headOfService_ids.get(Id).CommunityNickname+'';

return channelName;
```

}

with the following

```
 public static String setSlackUserNickName(String businessUnit) {
    String channelName;
    
    Set<Id> headOfService_Ids = new Set<Id>();
    
    Map<Id, Application_Parameters__c> headOfService = New Map<Id, Application_Parameters__c>(
        [SELECT Id, Head_of_Service__c FROM Application_Parameters__c WHERE Business_Unit__c = :businessUnit]);
   
    for(Application_Parameters__c app : headOfService.values()) {
        headOfService_ids.add(app.Head_of_Service__c);
        System.debug('Head Of Service for ' +businessUnit+ ' is ' +headOfService_Ids);
    }
    
    Map<ID,User> headOfServiceMap = new Map<ID,User>([SELECT CommunityNickname FROM User WHERE Id = :headOfService_Ids]);
    System.debug('Map hos ' +headOfServiceMap.values().CommunityNickname);
    channelName = '@'+headOfServiceMap.values().CommunityNickname+'';
    
    System.debug('Channel Name Apac is ' +channelName);
    
    return channelName;
}
```

I am now able to send alert to the head of service for a business unit...
Not sure if my code is written the best way possible but it's still better than my initial code with endless **if statements**